# Delphi - Using the TApplicationEvents OnShortCut event to detect Alt+C key presses

Tags: delphi, vcl

I am using TApplicationEvents OnShortCut event to get application keyboard short cuts in a Delphi program.

Using the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1ShortCut(var Msg: TWMKey; var Handled: Boolean) ;
begin
   if (Msg.CharCode = VK_F9) then
   begin
     ShowMessage('F9 pressed!') ;
     Handled := True;
   end;
end;
```

Question:

How do I detect when 'ALT C' has been pressed ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like so:

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1ShortCut(var Msg: TWMKey;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if (Msg.CharCode = Ord('C'))
    and (HiWord(Msg.KeyData) and KF_ALTDOWN <> 0)
  then begin
    ShowMessage('Alt+C pressed!') ;
    Handled := TRUE;
  end;
end;
```

Please note that using Alt and some key only is a bad choice for a shortcut, as the system uses these to activate menu items or dialog controls.

Comment: my sweet Delphi :) damn all java... (i'm just currently very upset about the Java world)

Answer (score 2):

Or you can create simple TAction, they eats shortcuts before others.