# Delphi: Convert keys to letters, ignoring shiftsate

Tags: delphi, keyboard

I'm trying to make a search feature where the user can hold in the control key and type some text to search.
I'm using the OnKeyDown/OnKeyUp to trap the control key.

Is there a easy way to check if the key parameter given to the onKeyUp/Down event is a litteral?
Or is it possible to convert the char given to OnKeyPressed while holding down the control key to the char it would have been if the control key where not pressed?

Edit:
I need a solution that can handle letters beyond the simple a..z range, like æ, ø å.

It looks like Delphi 2009 got a couple of useful methods in the TCharachter-class; e.g. `function IsLetterOrDigit(C: Char): Boolean;`

I'm stuck with delphi 2007, though...

Answer (score 2):

The OnKeyDown & OnKeyPress Events have a number of Limitations.

Rather use a **TApplicationEvents** Component.

In it's  **OnShortCut** Event hander use the following code

```
procedure TFormA.ApplicationEvents1ShortCut(var Msg: TWMKey; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if (Msg.CharCode = Ord('B')) and (HiWord(Msg.KeyData) and KF_ALTDOWN <> 0)  then
  begin
    Handled := True;
   // Do what needs to be done;
  end;

end;
```

This will trap ALT-B

have a look at [Delphi - Using the TApplicationEvents OnShortCut event to detect Alt+C key presses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734990/delphi-using-the-tapplicationevents-onshortcut-event-to-detect-altc-key-pressed) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the Key(Char) parameter from OnKeyPress event to it's ordinal value using Ord(Key) however, in the OnKeyDown event you can do the following

```
if CharInSet(Char(Key), ['A'..'Z']) then
  do something
```

you might also want to play with ShiftState to check if ALT, CTRL and/or SHIFT key is down...

Answer (score 0):

Here you have all the info:

- [Virtual Key Codes](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/l/blvkc.htm)
- [Understanding and Processing Keyboard events in Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/keyboard_events.htm)